# tkinter - Is it possible to initialize a variable using a winfo_id?

Tags: tkinter, winapi, x11

I need to control the same window in two python processes.

in one process: **main.py**

```py
window = tk.Tk()
win_id = window.winfo_id()

proc = subprocess.Popen(["./second.py","run",str(win_id)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
window.withdraw()
```

in another process: **second.py**

```py
#here tk won't create another window, but will take control on the window refered by win_id
def run(win_id):
    window = tk.Tk(win_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv
    globals()[args[1]](*args[2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control one window from two processes. Your only option is to set up some sort of interprocess communication where you send information from the second process back to the first, and then the first can use that information to run commands.

Comment: In the 1st script, after calling the process, I need to hide the window (withdraw), in that case, is it possible the 2nd script sends output to the 1st?

Comment: @danilo: as long as the first process is still running, you can send information to it.